# Filtering a View that is output as a Block

Tags: views, 6, ajax

I have a view which has a page display and a block display. The block display has Use Ajax enabled so the filters show up. When I output the block display to my template using:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('list_disciplines', 'block_1'); ?>
```

It outputs correctly, and shows the filters. The problem is when I submit the filters form it redirects me to the path I have set up for the page display, and doesn't use ajax at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally dug up my answer.

http://drupal.org/node/386388

In summary, the scripts for ajax views cannot be added if you embed your view in a page template. You either have to create the view in preprocess_page or in a node template file.